# LINQ query to filter based on Substring of a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query that returns a list called "results". I then need to filter that list to exclude any records that have a Substring of the first two characters in another list.

My initial results have a count of 36 and after running the following the filteredResults also has a count of 36. I made sure that the list of delayCodes includes a value that should be found on at least two records returned in the "results" list.

```
var delayCodes = new string[] { "AT", "FA", "FC", "FP", "MI", "MT", "SD" };

var filteredResults = results.Select(i => !delayCodes.Contains(i.DLY_CODE.Substring(0,2)));
```

I've done some searching and I see where some suggest using .StartsWith but they typically look at a specific value like .StartsWith("xx"). I don't know how to tell the query to look at my list of codes.

Any suggestions on how I can get something like this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `Where` if you want to filter:

```
var filteredResults = results.Where(i => !delayCodes.Contains(i.DLY_CODE.Substring(0,2)));
```

Here is a more efficient(on large collections) approach which uses a LINQ "Left Join":

```
var filteredResults =
    from res in results
    join code in delayCodes
    on res.DLY_CODE.Substring(0, 2) equals code into gj
    from lj in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where lj == null
    select res;
```

Comment: Thanks! I initially tried the .Where which didn't work so I tried the .Select which didn't work either. I'll test out your suggested code and let you know how that works.

Comment: I think your suggested efficient approach is going to work. When I ran it the results went from an initial count of 38 down to 19. I will go back and look through the results to confirm it all is working but I'm sure it is. I don't understand all of what your code is doing so I'll have to study it more.

Answer (score 2):

Alternativly to Tims solution:

```
var filteredResults = results.Where(i => delayCodes.All(x => x != i.DLY_CODE.Substring(0,2)));
```

Comment: I tried this one but the initial results and the filteredResults came back with the same count. I'll have to go look at the data to verify some things. Question though, I thought I read that using .ALL will find the first condition that was met and then ignore the rest. Ex: if 5 records started with "SD" once it found the first one it would ignore the rest. So instead of excluding all 5 it would only exclude 1?

Comment: No, actually it tests if all members of a collection pass a condition. It stops when the first element was found that does NOT pass the condition. So for every element witihin `result` it checks if there if ALL elements within `delayCodes` are different from the former.